# How to modify this Correlation Matrix plot?

Tags: r, plot, correlation

I have the following codes to display a correlation matrix,

```
panel.cor <- function(x, y, digits=2, prefix="", cex.cor)
{
    usr <- par("usr"); on.exit(par(usr))
    par(usr = c(0, 1, 0, 1))
    r <- abs(cor(x, y))
    txt <- format(c(r, 0.123456789), digits=digits)[1]
    txt <- paste(prefix, txt, sep="")
    if(missing(cex.cor)) cex <- 0.8/strwidth(txt)

    test <- cor.test(x,y)
    # borrowed from printCoefmat
    Signif <- symnum(test$p.value, corr = FALSE, na = FALSE,
                  cutpoints = c(0, 0.001, 0.01, 0.05, 0.1, 1),
                  symbols = c("***", "**", "*", ".", " "))

    text(0.5, 0.5, txt, cex = cex * r)
    text(.8, .8, Signif, cex=cex, col=2)
}
pairs(USJudgeRatings[,c(2:3,6,1,7)],
  lower.panel=panel.smooth, upper.panel=panel.cor)
```

I want to modify the plot like:

1. Have smaller blue dots as

   ```
   pairs(USJudgeRatings[,c(2:3,6,1,7)],
         main="xxx",
         pch=18,
         col="blue",
         cex=0.8)
   ```
2. Include a histogram of the entries on the diagonal (as seen in [enter link description here](http://gettinggeneticsdone.blogspot.co.uk/2012/08/more-on-exploring-correlations-in-r.html))
3. Display the correlation and p-value as

   ```
   r=0.9;
   p=0.001;
   ```

with values not stars.

There is a fitting line displayed for the scatter plot of the paired data. What is the method used for the fitting? Which line is defined the fitting as the codes shown above? And how to change the fitting method?

Comment: You ask a lot but you don't show what you have tried. I think that you have more luck to do this within lattice package. see `?splom`.

Comment: @agstudy Sorry, I am pretty new to R language. I am not sure how to do this. I tried pairs(USJudgeRatings[,c(2:3,6,1,7)],
  lower.panel=panel.smooth, upper.panel=panel.cor, pch=18, col="blue") but got some errors.

Comment: There is a fitting line displayed for the scatter plot of the paired data. What is the method used for the fitting? Which line is defined the fitting as the codes shown above? And how to change the fitting method?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Help page for the function `pairs()` gives you example how to define panels to plot.

For your particular case:

Changed `panel.cor()` function to show to lines of text - p-values and correlation coefficients.

```
panel.cor <- function(x, y, digits=2, cex.cor)
{
  usr <- par("usr"); on.exit(par(usr))
  par(usr = c(0, 1, 0, 1))
  r <- abs(cor(x, y))
  txt <- format(c(r, 0.123456789), digits=digits)[1]
  test <- cor.test(x,y)
  Signif <- ifelse(round(test$p.value,3)<0.001,"p<0.001",paste("p=",round(test$p.value,3)))  
  text(0.5, 0.25, paste("r=",txt))
  text(.5, .75, Signif)
}
```

For `panel.smooth()` function defined `cex=`, `col=` and `pch=` arguments.

```
panel.smooth<-function (x, y, col = "blue", bg = NA, pch = 18, 
                        cex = 0.8, col.smooth = "red", span = 2/3, iter = 3, ...) 
{
  points(x, y, pch = pch, col = col, bg = bg, cex = cex)
  ok <- is.finite(x) & is.finite(y)
  if (any(ok)) 
    lines(stats::lowess(x[ok], y[ok], f = span, iter = iter), 
          col = col.smooth, ...)
}
```

To add histograms, `panel.hist()` functions should be defined (taken from help file of `pairs()`)

```
panel.hist <- function(x, ...)
{
  usr <- par("usr"); on.exit(par(usr))
  par(usr = c(usr[1:2], 0, 1.5) )
  h <- hist(x, plot = FALSE)
  breaks <- h$breaks; nB <- length(breaks)
  y <- h$counts; y <- y/max(y)
  rect(breaks[-nB], 0, breaks[-1], y, col="cyan", ...)
}
```

Final plot:

```
pairs(USJudgeRatings[,c(2:3,6,1,7)],
          lower.panel=panel.smooth, upper.panel=panel.cor,diag.panel=panel.hist)
```

[image]

Comment: Does anyone know how to pass the `cex.cor` variable in the `pairs()` call? I presume this is used in the `panel.cor()` function for `text()`, while not in. But adding it generates a lot of warnings!

Answer (score 0):

Modified Scatter Plot Matrix

1. %% Modified function for histogram;

   ```
   panel.hist <- function(x, ...)
   {
   usr <- par("usr"); on.exit(par(usr))
   par(usr = c(usr[1:2], 0, 1.5) )
   par(cex.axis=2, family="Times New Roman", face="bold", size=12, cex.lab=1, cex.main=1, cex.sub=1)
   h <- hist(x, plot = FALSE)
   breaks <- h$breaks; nB <- length(breaks)
   y <- h$counts; y <- y/max(y)
   rect(breaks[-nB], 0, breaks[-1], y, col="cyan", ...)

   }
   ```
2. %% Modified Regression Function with `panel.smooth`;

   ```
   panel.smooth<-function (x, y, col = "black", bg = NA, pch = 16, 
                   cex = 2, col.smooth = "red", span = 2/3, iter = 3, ...) 
   {
   points(x, y, pch = pch, col = col, bg = bg, cex = cex)
   ok <- is.finite(x) & is.finite(y)
   if (any(ok)) 
   lines(stats::lowess(x[ok], y[ok], f = span, iter = iter), 
         col = col.smooth, ...)
   }
   ```
3. %% Modified Correlation Function with `panel.cor`;

   ```
   panel.cor <- function(x, y, digits=2, cex.cor)
   {
   usr <- par("usr"); on.exit(par(usr))
   par(usr = c(0, 1, 0, 1))
   r <- abs(cor(x, y))
   txt <- format(c(r, 0.123456789), digits=digits)[1]
   test <- cor.test(x,y)
   Signif <- ifelse(round(test$p.value,3)<0.001,"p < 0.001",paste("p = ",round(test$p.value,3)))  
   text(0.5, 0.25, paste("r = ",txt), cex = 2.5, family="Times New Roman", face="bold", size=12)
   text(.5, .75, Signif, cex = 2.5, family="Times New Roman", face="bold", size=12)
   }
   ```

To be able to plot the scatterplot matrix, you also need to install "Times New Roman" font. To do it, follow the steps below;

4. %% Install all fonts into RStudio. This is important to improve the quality of the plot!

   ```
   install.packages("extrafont") # Install fonts
   library(extrafont)            # Install library
   font_import()                 # Import all fonts  
   loadfonts(device="win")       # Register fonts for Windows bitmap output
   fonts()                       # Finish the process
   ```
5. %% Finally, plot your figure with `pairs` function;

   ```
    pairs(qq1, lower.panel=panel.smooth, upper.panel=panel.cor ,diag.panel=panel.hist, cex = 2, cex.labels = 2, cex.main = 2)
   ```
6. %% Check the final product;
       [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6cH0M.png)