# Adding line of identity to correlation plots using pairs() command in R

Tags: r, correlation, scatter-plot

Similar to a [prevous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15271103/how-to-modify-this-correlation-matrix-plot/15271627#15271627), I'd like to modify the following code ([from example in the R documentation for pairs() command](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/pairs.html)):

```
## put (absolute) correlations on the upper panels,
## with size proportional to the correlations.
panel.cor <- function(x, y, digits = 2, prefix = "", cex.cor, ...)
{
    usr <- par("usr"); on.exit(par(usr))
    par(usr = c(0, 1, 0, 1))
    r <- abs(cor(x, y))
    txt <- format(c(r, 0.123456789), digits = digits)[1]
    txt <- paste0(prefix, txt)
    if(missing(cex.cor)) cex.cor <- 0.8/strwidth(txt)
    text(0.5, 0.5, txt, cex = cex.cor * r)
}
pairs(USJudgeRatings, lower.panel = panel.smooth, upper.panel = panel.cor)
```

Instead of a loess line, I want a line of identity for each plot. The secret lies in the $"panel.smooth" function, but I don't know how to modify it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you just mean something like this:

```
my_line <- function(x,y,...){
    points(x,y,...)
    abline(a = 0,b = 1,...)
}
pairs(USJudgeRatings, lower.panel = my_line, upper.panel = panel.cor)
```

Comment: @joran can you please explain why you added three line in a function?

Answer (score 1):

Or, if you want to plot a fitted, linear line, then you could modify [joran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/324364/joran)'s answer:

```
my_line <- function(x,y,...){
    points(x,y,...)
    abline(a = lm(y ~ x)$coefficients[1] , b = lm(y ~ x)$coefficients[2] , ...)
}
```

If you are indeed using pairs, however, it seems like loess would be more appropriate since you are likely exploring a dataset and would warrant the fitting of a linear line as extraneous at that point.

Comment: better coding style (and more computationally efficient) would be:
`fit <- lm(y ~ x)`
`abline(a = fit$coefficients[1] , b = fit$coefficients[2] , ...)`