# 45 degree line in Plot function in R

Tags: r, plot

I have data like this :

```
df <- data.frame(X=rnorm(10,0,1), Y=rnorm(10,0,1), Z=rnorm(10,0,1))
```

I need to plot each variables against each other, so I used

```
plot(df)
```

It plotted each variable within the df against the each other exactly what is required.

But I want to add 45 degree line(where x=y), in each and every sub plot. I want to know how it can be done ? I also tried  through loop but due to "space constraint" it could not happen[in reality i have 5 variables within the df]. Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Check out [abline](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/abline.html). It lets you add a straight line to an already-plotted graph. The `coef` arg should be of interest to you. It takes a vector of length two giving the intercept and slope.

Comment: @Tgsmith61591  It won't work.

Comment: Then you need to share the code where you're trying that.

Comment: No it is not working. I have tried for it. It work for individual plot only.

Comment: Yes, it only works for the *current plot*. You'll have to use it between each `plot` command.

Comment: @Tgsmith61591  Again, it won't work

Comment: You need to start sharing some code if you want any help

Comment: @Tgsmith61591 did you run the code and data OP provided with your solution? Because it doesn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`plot(df)` calls `pairs` to plot data.frames. So, using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17793899/3710546), we can try:

```
my_line <- function(x,y,...){
    points(x,y,...)
    segments(min(x), min(y), max(x), max(y),...)
}
pairs(df, lower.panel = my_line, upper.panel = my_line)
```

[image]

Comment: This is a fantastic answer

Comment: Thanks. It is an amazing.

Comment: @Pascal.. How do you think so fast ? :)

Comment: Can you please explain three dots in your function ?

Comment: why it has been added ?

Comment: @Neeraj dots are often there in functions passed to other functions to allow for specification of additional arguments.

Comment: @Heroka... can you explain for the above function ?

Comment: @Pascal? I don't feel qualified to explain your solution.

Comment: I just followed the example in the linked answer. Also, in the examples given in the help page of `pairs`, `...` is used, probably for compatibility purpose. Sorry, I cannot explain more in details.