# Add lines to Scatterplot in R

Tags: r, scatter-plot

How to add lines to the chart?
I did following

```
dat <- data.frame(xvar = 1:20 - rnorm(20,sd=10),
                  yvar = 1:20 - rnorm(20,sd=10),
                  zvar = 1:20 - rnorm(20,sd=10))
plot(dat[,1:3])
```

[image: Result]

But I need horizontal and vertical lines at the value zero of all variables, like this
[image: Required]

Comment: have you looked at the R abline() function? It's made for this. See: http://www.endmemo.com/program/R/line.php for live examples

Comment: AFAIK `abline` won't work on this multiplot. You'd need to plot each scatter separately, draw the lines and then move to the next one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this might work:

```
##define a function to use in pairs
plotfun <- function(x,y,...){
    points(x,y,...) #plot them
    abline(h = 0) #horizontal line
    abline(v = 0) #vertical line
}
pairs(dat, upper.panel = plotfun)
```

[image: Result]

Note that this question is very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17793690/adding-line-of-identity-to-correlation-plots-using-pairs-command-in-r).