# Insert abline(s) through all scatterplots in a scatterplot matrix

Tags: r, scatter-plot

I am wondering if it is possible to insert ablines across all relevant plots in a scatterplot matrix such that the values can be visually compared throughout all plots? Here is an example with lines manually drawn in:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UK1kc.png)

Comment: Can you provide some sample code? I haven't looked at scatterplots in a while, and don't feel like googling for a refresher...

Comment: I can think of three ways of getting a scatterplot matrix. Posting images does not tell us what you are using although it suggests perhaps using base graphics. There are probably ways of tacking that request and posting sample data and code is expected on SO.

Comment: See if this question/answer helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37008771/add-lines-to-scatterplot-in-r/37010652#37010652

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
abline(h=value, col='red') #for horizontal line
abline(v=value, col='red') #for vertical line
abline(y~x, col='red') #for some regression function
```

where 'value' is any point on 'y' or 'x' axis.