# incorporate standalone legend in ggpairs (take 2)

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggally

**tl;dr** can't get a standalone legend (describing common colours across the whole plot) in `ggpairs` to my satisfaction.

Sorry for length.

I'm trying to draw a (lower-triangular) pairs plot using `GGally::ggpairs` (an extension package for drawing various kinds of plot matrices with `ggplot2`).  This is essentially the same question as [How to add an external legend to ggpairs()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22945702/how-to-add-an-external-legend-to-ggpairs) , but I'm not satisfied with the answer to that question aesthetically, so I'm posting this as an extension (if suggested/recommended by commenters, I will delete this question and offer a bounty on that question instead).  In particular, I would like the legend to appear *outside* the sub-plot frame, either putting it within one virtual subplot but allowing additional width to hold it, or (ideally) putting it in a separate (empty) subplot.  As I show below, both of my partial solutions have problems.

Fake data:

```
set.seed(101)
dd <- data.frame(x=rnorm(100),
                 y=rnorm(100),
                 z=rnorm(100),
                 f=sample(c("a","b"),size=100,replace=TRUE))
library(GGally)
```

Base plot function:

```
ggfun <- function(...) {
   ggpairs(dd,mapping = ggplot2::aes(color = f),
    columns=1:3,
    lower=list(continuous="points"),
    diag=list(continuous="blankDiag"),
    upper=list(continuous="blank"),
    ...)
}
```

Function to trim top/right column:

```
trim_gg <- function(gg) {
    n <- gg$nrow
    gg$nrow <- gg$ncol <- n-1
    v <- 1:n^2
    gg$plots <- gg$plots[v>n & v%%n!=0]
    gg$xAxisLabels <- gg$xAxisLabels[-n]
    gg$yAxisLabels <- gg$yAxisLabels[-1]
    return(gg)
}

gg0 <- trim_gg(ggfun(legends=TRUE))
```

Get rid of legends in left column (as in the linked question above):

```
library(ggplot2)  ## for theme()
for (i in 1:2) {
   inner <- getPlot(gg0,i,1)
   inner <- inner + theme(legend.position="none")
   gg0 <- putPlot(gg0,inner,i,1)
}
inner <- getPlot(gg0,2,2)
inner <- inner + theme(legend.position="right")
gg0 <- putPlot(gg0,inner,2,2)
```

[image]

**Problems**:

- the blank panel behind the legend is actually masking some points; I don't know why it's not outside the panel as usual, I assume that's something that `ggpairs` is doing
- if it were outside the panel (on top or to the right), I would want to make sure to leave some extra space so the panels themselves were all the same size. However, `ggmatrix`/`ggpairs` looks very inflexible about this.

The only alternative I've been able to try to far is following [ggplot separate legend and plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12539348/ggplot-separate-legend-and-plot) by extracting the legend and using `gridExtra::grid.arrange()`:

```
g_legend <- function(a.gplot){
   tmp <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(a.gplot))
   leg <- which(sapply(tmp$grobs, function(x) x$name) == "guide-box")
   legend <- tmp$grobs[[leg]]
   return(legend)
}

library(gridExtra)
grid.arrange(getPlot(gg0,1,1),
             g_legend(getPlot(gg0,2,2)),
             getPlot(gg0,2,1),
             getPlot(gg0,2,2)+theme(legend.position="none"),
   nrow=2)
```

[image]

**Problems**:

- the axes and labels suppressed by `ggpairs` are back ...

I also considered creating a panel with a special plot that contained only the legend (i.e. trying to use `theme(SOMETHING=element.blank)` to suppress the plot itself, but couldn't figure out how to do it.

As a last resort, I could trim the axes where appropriate myself, but this is practically reinventing what `ggpairs` is doing in the first place ...

Comment: I don't have time to look into this right now, but I think the best way would be a modification of the `ggpairs` function. The package maintainer was very responsive when I last suggested a (small) improvement to it.

Comment: I'm not quite sure if this is what you want, but, in solution 1, position the legend into the empty panel. That is, change the second last line to: `inner <- inner + theme(legend.position=c(.5, 1.5)) `

Comment: Still in solution 1: It's easier to leave `legends` set to `FALSE` so that there is no need to remove the  legends.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With some slight modification to solution 1: First, draw the matrix of plots without their legends (but still with the colour mapping). Second, use your `trim_gg` function to remove the diagonal spaces. Third, for the plot in the top left position, draw its legend but position it into the empty space to the right.

```
data(state)
dd <- data.frame(state.x77,
             State = state.name,
             Abbrev = state.abb,
             Region = state.region,
             Division = state.division) 

columns <- c(3, 5, 6, 7)
colour <- "Region"

library(GGally)
library(ggplot2)  ## for theme()

# Base plot
ggfun <- function(data = NULL, columns = NULL, colour = NULL, legends = FALSE) {
   ggpairs(data, 
     columns = columns,
     mapping = ggplot2::aes_string(colour = colour),
     lower = list(continuous = "points"),
     diag = list(continuous = "blankDiag"),
     upper = list(continuous = "blank"),
    legends = legends)
}

# Remove the diagonal elements
trim_gg <- function(gg) {
    n <- gg$nrow
    gg$nrow <- gg$ncol <- n-1
    v <- 1:n^2
    gg$plots <- gg$plots[v > n & v%%n != 0]
    gg$xAxisLabels <- gg$xAxisLabels[-n]
    gg$yAxisLabels <- gg$yAxisLabels[-1]
    return(gg)
}

# Get the plot
gg0 <- trim_gg(ggfun(dd, columns, colour))

# For plot in position (1,1), draw its legend in the empty panels to the right
inner <- getPlot(gg0, 1, 1)

inner <- inner + 
   theme(legend.position = c(1.01, 0.5), 
         legend.direction = "horizontal",
         legend.justification = "left") +
   guides(colour = guide_legend(title.position = "top"))  

gg0 <- putPlot(gg0, inner, 1, 1)
gg0
```

[image]